# Vim jump back over spaces inside of curled braces

Tags: vim, vi

Lets say, I have wrote this piece of LaTeX in vim:

```
A_{\vec B}_
          ^
         Cursor
```

The cursor is at the marked position. Now I want to add a `\vec` in front of the A.

I tried `<Esc>Bi\vec <Esc>WW` but I want `B` and `W` to jump over spaces which are inside of curled braces.

Any ideas how to do that?

Edit: Maybe I should've wrote, that I wanted to map this to a shortcut. `A` and `B` are just Examples for Strings which do not include spaces.

SOLUTION: I think I have found, what I was searching. With `?` you can do a backward search with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make `B` or `W` treat a braced string as a Word, but you can use `%` to jump from one end of a braced string to the other.

Answer (score 1):

`FAi\vec`<kbd>ESC</kbd>`$`

Does it assuming that B is really at the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve a similar job. `W` and `B` only stop at whitespaces, as far as I know, so you can jump twice between words with `2B`, or set insert mode at the beginning with `I`, or search for a letter, with `f`, `F`, `t` or `T`. Also `0` and `$` to go to the beginning or end directly. There are many possibilities. I hope one of them can be useful instead.

Comment: Maybe I should've wrote, that I wanted to map this to a shortcut. `A` and `B` are just Examples for Strings which do not include spaces.